# Why these conclusions from the definition? Absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, absolute-value

I know the definition is
\begin{align}
\lvert x \rvert =
\begin{cases}
x, \quad &x\geq 0 \\
-x, \quad &x<0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

But why can we conclude that $x \leq \lvert x\rvert $?

And if $x \leq \lvert x\rvert $ is true, why can we also write $-\lvert x \rvert \leq x \leq \lvert x \rvert$?

I don't understand these conclusions just from the definition.

Thanks!

Comment: Excuse my snarkiness, but It seems you haven't *thought about* the definition.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible cases:

Case $1$:

$x \geq 0 \Rightarrow |x| = x$

Case $2$:

$x < 0 \Rightarrow -x > 0 \Rightarrow |x|=-x>x$

Therefore, by 'exhaustion' of all cases, $|x| \geq x$

Comment: And, similarly, $x\ge-\lvert x\rvert$